# Select top rows in R using add_tally and top_n functions

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to select the top *n* rows in a data frame for which I
calculated a column `n` that represents the sum of a variable. For example,
using the `mtcars` data, I would like to filter to keep only the two `cyl`
with the greatest sum of `mpg`. In the following example, I was expecting
to select all rows where `cyl == 4` and `cyl == 8`. It must be simple, but
I can not figure out my mistake.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(sum(mpg))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl `sum(mpg)`
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     4       293.
#> 2     6       138.
#> 3     8       211.

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% # Calculate the sum of mpg for each cyl 
  add_tally(mpg, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  top_n(2, n)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 12
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb     n
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1  293.
#>  2  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2  293.
#>  3  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2  293.
#>  4  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1  293.
#>  5  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2  293.
#>  6  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1  293.
#>  7  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1  293.
#>  8  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1  293.
#>  9  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2  293.
#> 10  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2  293.
#> 11  21.4     4 121     109  4.11  2.78  18.6     1     1     4     2  293.
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think that you are looking for `mtcars %>% 
 group_by(cyl) %>% # 
 add_tally(mpg, sort = TRUE) %>% 
 ungroup() %>%
 filter(dense_rank(desc(n)) < 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `top_n` returns the top `n` rows **after ordering the dataframe** and returns more than `n` rows if there are ties. It **does not** return rows with distinct top `n` values.

From documentation -

> **Usage**
>
> top_n(x, n, wt)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> x:    a tbl() to filter
>
> n:     number of rows to return. If x is grouped,
>   this is the number of rows per group. **Will include more than n rows if
>   there are ties**. If n is positive, selects the top n rows. If negative,
>   selects the bottom n rows.

You need, as suggested by @tmfmnk -

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  add_tally(mpg, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(dense_rank(desc(n)) < 3)
```